# jQuery maphilight set area to alwaysOn by click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using David Lynch's jQuery maphilight (http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/) to highlight image map areas over an image. In particular, this demo (http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_features.html) shows how to set data-maphilight="{'alwaysOn:true'}" so that a given map area is "always on".

I want to set "always on" based on items that are clicked. So I tried this:

```
$(this).attr('data-maphilight', '{\'alwaysOn\':true}');
```

Using Firebug, I can see that the attribute is being added to my element when it is clicked, for example:

```
<area data-county="Susquehanna" href="#" coords="589,62,590,117,518,118,511,62" shape="poly" data-maphilight="{'alwaysOn':true}">
```

However, the element is not staying highlighted.

If I manually (in the HTML markup) set alwaysOn, like this:

```
<area shape="poly" coords="447,193,442,225,453,222,467,226,467,235,472,235,475,242,486,242,489,251,448,268,420,276,433,257,434,246,438,235,428,220,433,206,430,194,438,191" href="#" data-county="Northumberland" data-maphilight='{"alwaysOn":true}'>
```

...it does work. Is this a mixup of the single vs. double quotes? When I use the jQuery "attr" statement, it automatically uses double quotes, so I had to reverse them. OR, is this a problem where just setting that attribute is not causing the jQuery plugin to update?

Would appreciate any advice as I try to modify this script to do what I want.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a mixup of the single vs. double quotes?

When you set the data attribute. jQuery tries to parse the string as a JSON but only if it is a valid [JSON](http://json.org/). So, `data-maphilight='{"alwaysOn":true}'` includes a valid JSON while `data-maphilight="{'alwaysOn':true}"`. Note the single quote for delimiting strings produces a wrong JSON.

> is this a problem where just setting that attribute is not causing the jQuery plugin to update?

Well, it is different setting the data attribute than setting the data object.

```
// Changes the data-maphilight attribute to the string '{\'alwaysOn\':true}'
$(this).attr('data-maphilight', '{\'alwaysOn\':true}');
// Sets the internal data object to {'alwaysOn': true}. This is a javascript object, not JSON.
$(this).data('maphilight', {'alwaysOn': true});
```

So once the object is created, if you want to modify it you need to use `.data` not `.attr`.

The problem with changing a property not causing the update is probably because we need a way to notify the plugin a change was happened. I've seen in the sample code you refer that this plugin uses `.trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight')` to fire this notification. Then, the full change statement should be something like this:

```
$(this).data('maphilight', {'alwaysOn': true}).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
```

Note that doing this assignment will replace the current `maphilight` data object to `{'alwaysOn': true}` replacing the previous one.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful, and this works. I'm gaining a better understanding of attr vs. data. I'm still a little confused about what trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight') does exactly, though. Or why that is needed in addition to the "data" part.